# How to combine different columns in a dataframe using comprehension-python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, nan, string-concatenation

Suppose a dataframe contains

```
attacker_1 attacker_2  attacker_3  attacker_4
Lannister   nan         nan         nan
nan         Stark       greyjoy     nan
```

I want to create another column called AttackerCombo that aggregates the 4 columns into 1 column. 
How would I go about defining such code in python?
I have been practicing python and I reckon a list comprehension of this sort makes sense, but [list(x) for x in attackers]
where attackers is a numpy array of the 4 columns displays all 4 columns aggregated into 1 column, however I would like to remove all the nans as well.
So the result for each row instead of looking like

```
starknannanlannister
```

would look like

```
stark/lannister
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `join` and remove `NaN` by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df['attackers'] = df[['attacker_1','attacker_2','attacker_3','attacker_4']] \
                    .apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
print (df)
  attacker_1 attacker_2 attacker_3  attacker_4      attackers
0  Lannister        NaN        NaN         NaN      Lannister
1        NaN      Stark    greyjoy         NaN  Stark/greyjoy
```

If need `separator` empty string use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df['attackers'] = df[['attacker_1','attacker_2','attacker_3','attacker_4']].fillna('') \
                    .apply(''.join, axis=1)
print (df)
  attacker_1 attacker_2 attacker_3  attacker_4     attackers
0  Lannister        NaN        NaN         NaN     Lannister
1        NaN      Stark    greyjoy         NaN  Starkgreyjoy
```

Another 2 solutions with `list comprehension` - first compare by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) and second check if `string`:

```
df['attackers'] = df[['attacker_1','attacker_2','attacker_3','attacker_4']] \
                    .apply(lambda x: '/'.join([e for e in x if pd.notnull(e)]), axis=1)
print (df)
  attacker_1 attacker_2 attacker_3  attacker_4      attackers
0  Lannister        NaN        NaN         NaN      Lannister
1        NaN      Stark    greyjoy         NaN  Stark/greyjoy


#python 3 - isinstance(e, str), python 2 - isinstance(e, basestring)
df['attackers'] = df[['attacker_1','attacker_2','attacker_3','attacker_4']] \
                    .apply(lambda x: '/'.join([e for e in x if isinstance(e, str)]), axis=1)
print (df)
  attacker_1 attacker_2 attacker_3  attacker_4      attackers
0  Lannister        NaN        NaN         NaN      Lannister
1        NaN      Stark    greyjoy         NaN  Stark/greyjoy
```

Comment: Perfect Solution! Thanks. Can you expand on the lines of 'axis', as per the documentation if axis =0, then function is applied on column and if axis=1 then it is applied on the row, can you explain how that works here?

Comment: exactly as you say in comment. you can test it by `df[['attacker_1','attacker_2','attacker_3','attacker_4']].apply(print)` and `df[['attacker_1','attacker_2','attacker_3','attacker_4']].apply(print, axis=1)`

Comment: Let me try to explain what I know so far, when I take a subset of say 4 columns and I apply a function using apply, then 'lambda x' is an iterable over all the rows in the subset and the function being applied here is 'a string "/" concatenated with dropna being applied on each row and this is specified using axis=1'. Is that correct or am I missing something

Comment: Can you suggest some more nuances of the same operation? as in a list comprehension for example , what I had in mind is look at each element in a row and check if its NaN, and then add the non NaNs into a list. That might solve the problem with some performance hindrance.

Comment: I add 2 another solutions, I hope they are faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a new column in the dataframe that you will fill thanks to a lambda function:

```
df['attackers'] = df[['attacker_1','attacker_2','attacker_3','attacker_4']].apply(lambda x : '{}{}{}{}'.format(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]), axis=1)
```

You don't specify *how* you want to aggregate them, so for instance, if you want separated by a dash:

```
df['attackers'] = df[['attacker_1','attacker_2','attacker_3','attacker_4']].apply(lambda x : '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to compute similar operation using numpy, lets suppose the dataframe is converted to numpy. And what are the other possible comprehension functions that can be used. Thank you

Comment: I tried to modify the command @nlassaux has provided, battledf[['attacker_1','attacker_2','attacker_3','attacker_4']].fillna('').apply(lambda x : '{}{}{}{}'.format(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]), axis=1).unique().  This does generate a relevant solution. but Im not sure if this is an optimal one

Comment: Format is known to be optimal because it directly calls C code. Also, .apply() is fast but not as fast as pandas's built in parallel methods.